# c++, syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'N0'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have an issue compiling my code on windows.

On Unix-based systems all is working fine, but when I compile it on windows (currently with visual studio 2010 express), I'm getting the following errors:

> Error 253 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'N0' C:\ghost++\ghost\ohconnect.h 45
>
> Error 254 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int C:\ghost++\ghost\ohconnect.h 45
>
> Error 255 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int C:\ghost++\ghost\ohconnect.h 45
>
> Error 256 error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'N' C:\ghost++\ghost\ohconnect.h 46
>
> Error 257 error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int C:\ghost++\ghost\ohconnect.h 46

And so on.
I think it's all relating to my header file, the class itself is made to connect to websockets:

```
#ifndef OHConnect_H
#define OHConnect_H

//
// OHCONNECT
//

class CTCPClient;
class CBaseGame;
class CCommandPacket;
struct OHCHeader {
  unsigned header_size;
  bool fin;
  bool mask;
  enum opcode_type {
    CONTINUTATION = 0x0,
    TEXT_FRAME = 0x1,
    BINARY_FRAME = 0x2,
    CLOSE = 8,
    PING = 9,
    PONG = 0xa,
  } opcode;
  uint64_t N0;
  uint64_t N;
  uint8_t masking_key[4];
};
```

In my `.cpp` file I'm using `namespace std;` and included `<string>` only for windows.
But all this didnt work so far. I didnt wanted to put the whole files into the question since they are actually long.
Here is the full source:
[Headerfile](https://github.com/OHSystem/OHSystem/blob/master/ghost%2B%2B/ghost/ohconnect.h)
[Mainfile](https://github.com/OHSystem/OHSystem/blob/master/ghost%2B%2B/ghost/ohconnect.cpp)

What did I wrong here?

Comment: `#include`ing `stdint.h` should fix those errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler doesn't know the type `uint64_t` and `uint8_t`, add:

```
#include <cstdint>
```

Answer (score 2):

Note also that the trailing comma in the enum (after the definition `PONG = 0xa`) was only standardized in C++11, following the change made in C99. Older compilers or those running in a mode following the older 1998/2003 standard may trip over that as well.